# Transformar petición ajax a EcmaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

¿Cómo puedo convertir esto a una versión de javascript?

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'consulta.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : { alumnos: alumnos },
    })
```

Tengo algo así, pero no sé como mandarle la variable.

```
fetch('inc/consulta.php')
    .then(function (response){        
        return  response.json()        
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
fetch('inc/consulta.php', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: { alumnos: alumnos },
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function (response){        
    return  response.json()        
})
```